# La tournure "Ça sent le sapin" : est-elle courante ?

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques

L'expression "Ça sent le sapin" est-elle toujours courante ?

Comment: Je crois que son origine vient du fait que le sapin peut être utilisé pour fabriquer des cercueils (bon marché)

Comment: Je ne l'ai jamais entendu au Québec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elle l’est en France métropolitaine, je ne pourrais pas me prononcer pour les autres régions francophones. Elle est de surcroît transverse aux différentes couches sociales.

Comment: « Ça sent le sapin » signifie qu’une mort est imminente. Cela fait référence aux cercueils bon marchés généralement fait en bois de sapin

Comment: Merci, peut-être l'inclure à la réponse. Parfois il m'arrive de passer à côté d'un conifère en ville et d'arracher quelques aiguilles pour les frotter entre mes mains gantées parce que j'aime bien quand « ça sent le sapin ». Je ne connaissais pas cette expression-là.